# tilemap in sprite kit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, tile

This is about drawing a TileMap in SpriteKit. I get the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent:  name:'(null)' texture:['nil'] position:{64, 0} size:{0, 0} rotation:0.00'

This is my GameViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let scene = GameScene(size: CGSize(width: 1024, height: 768))
    // Configure the view.
    let skView = self.view as! SKView
    skView.showsFPS = true
    skView.showsNodeCount = true

    /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

    /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

    skView.presentScene(scene)
}
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
}
```

This is my GameScene.swift:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

let dungeon = SKNode()

let readableMap: [[Int]] = [
    [01, 00, 01, 01],
    [01, 00, 01, 01],
    [01, 00, 01, 01],
    [00, 01, 00, 01]]

override init(size: CGSize) {
    super.init(size: size)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */
    drawMap()
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
    }
}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}

func drawMap() {
    let map = readableMap.reverse()
    let tiles = [[Tile]](count: map.count, repeatedValue: [Tile](count: map[0].count, repeatedValue: Tile()))

    for i in 0..<map.count {
        for j in 0..<map[0].count {
            let tile = tiles[j][i]
            tile.position = CGPoint(x: j * Int(tile.tileSize.width), y: i * Int(tile.tileSize.height))
            dungeon.addChild(tile)
        }
    }
}
}
```

this is the class in Tile.swift:

```
import SpriteKit

class Tile: SKSpriteNode {
let tileSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 64, height: 64)
let tileTexture: SKTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "o")
}
```

what could be the reason? Thanks to anyone, I'm still learning.

Comment: Basically you tried to add a node which already has a parent to a second parent. This you cannot do, hence the error.

Comment: It's the loop under `dungeon.addChild)`, try running some debug messages

Comment: yes, that's basically what Xcode is saying. Is the class Tile legal as it's written?